# Trying to connect to google cloud storage and getting errors

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to connect to google cloud storage and i am facing issues shown below

```
ERROR  [Job]
Caught throwable org/threeten/bp/Duration java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/threeten/bp/Duration at com.google.api.gax.retrying.RetrySettings.newBuilder(RetrySettings.java:138)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getDefaultRetrySettingsBuilder(ServiceOptions.java:685)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<clinit>(ServiceOptions.java:85)
        at com.maf.core.order.impl.DefaultOrderService.uploadFileToGoogleCloud(DefaultOrderService.java:197)
        at com.maf.core.cronjob.consginmentJob.perform(consginmentJob.java:90)
        at com.maf.core.cronjob.consginmentJob.perform(consginmentJob.java:1)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob.performCronJob(ServicelayerJob.java:38)
        at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.execute(Job.java:1390)
        at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:814)
        at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.access$1(Job.java:767)
        at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job$JobRunable.run(Job.java:686)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.threadpool.PoolableThread.internalRun(PoolableThread.java:208)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:135)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.threeten.bp.Duration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.YURLClassLoader.loadRegisterAndResolveClass(YURLClassLoader.java:85)
        at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.YURLClassLoader.loadClass(YURLClassLoader.java:72)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
```

I am trying authenticate through

```
Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialFile)).createScoped(Lists.newArrayList(GOOGLE_CLOUD_PATH));
            Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

Comment: From the stacktrace it seems like you did not include some library.

Comment: I can give you all the list of libraries which i have added if you want but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: Could you provide the minimal code needed to reproduce the issue?

Comment: As PeS mentioned, your stack trace indicates that you are missing a library. We would require more information regarding how you are connecting to Cloud Storage.

Would it be possible for you to clarify what steps you have taken to connect to the Cloud Storage? Specifically, if you are connecting locally, via App engine or through a VM? This would allow us to narrow down the troubleshooting route of how you are importing your libraries.

Comment: Your stacktrace also indicates that you are using Java, please consider the following link [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) which highlights how to get started with Cloud Storage Client Libraries. It be my recommendation to use Maven to import your libraries as it is relatively straight forward. Also, would it be possible for you to post the results of your “mvn dependency:tree” and your config for the pom.xml file?